# Overloading = operator in c++ in case of strings

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading

I want to perform the following

```
int p = "xyz"
```

I should contain 3, i.e, the length of the string on the right side of =.

I tried making a class String with a char * data member but i was having trouble overloading the = operator since we have to pass atleast one object of the class we are overloading the operator for.

please help.

I tried to do the following:

```
friend void operator=(int, char*)
```

but it won't work since there is no argument of the class type.

Comment: It may be helpful: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/2137/

Comment: What, you don't know about [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen)?

Comment: i know about strlen but i need to do it using overloading without using any library functions..

Comment: @basant_androidBuilder: Without library functions: `int p = sizeof "xyz" - 1;`, or write your own `strlen`. Without unusual restrictions, use `std::string` for strings. You can't do it with overloading alone.

Comment: thanks.. but i was looking for a way using overloading...

Comment: any way using any method to perform the following?? `int p = "xyz"' so that p contains 3?

Comment: Cannot be done. Both int and char* are builtins. There is no class or struct to hang the operator definition on. What a lousy exam question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's impossible to do this, `operator=` is not overloadable for integer type.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049887/c-overloading-assignment-operator-for-default-types).

If you use `std::string`, the solution is simple:

```
std::string p = "abc";
int l = p.size(); // Better than l = p, because self describing
```